# ruby+ appium or java+appium for mobile native app automaion

Tags: java, ruby, appium

I am exploring appium for mobile native app automation.
Which client library is more stable and reliable with availability of documentation out of **ruby+appium** or **java+appium**.

Can any one please guide on same.

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to what language you prefer. Both have great support and gets updated frequently.
I personally use ruby+appium and then of course cucumber.
With ruby you can make use of ARC ("Appium Ruby Console"). With help with creating quality scripts: https://github.com/appium/ruby_console
Ruby also has an appium_lib library: https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib

Comment: Thank you @Dewald Schoonderwoerd ! I have already started working appium with java. The only issue now I am facing is with iOS appium XCUITest. Test cases run very slow and often fails due to crash. Really not sure what can be done to make it more faster and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on both Ruby and Java, implementation of Selenium and Appium, and I've felt that Ruby is a lot easier to grasp and code with, compared to Java- but this is completely a personal opinion. People may differ from this.

What I've felt is that Ruby is a lot easier to begin with and for people like your team members would definitely find it easy to learn, as compared to Java (again- a personal opinion).

It is a lot easier to write simple code in Ruby as compared to Java.

Let me take a simple example- A simple Hello world program

In Ruby, it would simple be as :

```
puts "Hello World"
```

or if you want an object oriented version

```
class HelloWorld
   def initialize(name)
      @name = name.capitalize
   end
   def sayHi
      puts "Hello #{@name}!"
   end
end

hello = HelloWorld.new("World")
hello.sayHi
```

Where as in Java, it would be :

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Hello, world!");
     }
}
```

A Ruby program is much smaller, simpler and easier to understand than a Java program, which comes in handy when you have a team, which has less or no technical prowess (programming knowledge).
It all depends on which language you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you @Manmohan_singh. I have chosen java over ruby. :)